# Angular routing not working with tabs

Tags: angular

I am using tab navigation for my profile page. The profile page holds the tab control. The problem occurs when the first tab equals to the root domain url the tab control does not navigate anymore when clickin the tabs.

Here is a plunkr demonstrating the problem:

https://plnkr.co/edit/emIJSNkxPuDxCjPSbXJy?p=preview

Maybe I am missing something but this could be bug in angular routing.

Is it possible to configure routing like this?

Here is the code for the tab routes

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: ProfileComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', loadChildren: 'src/user/subModule1/subModule1.module#SubModule1Module'},
            { path: 'subPath2', loadChildren: 'src/user/subModule2/subModule2.module#SubModule2Module' },
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want routing in your profile page which is on 'user/:id' route. Then root would be like

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
{
    path: 'user', component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', loadChildren: 'src/user/subModule1/subModule1.module#SubModule1Module'},
        { path: 'subPath2', loadChildren: 'src/user/subModule2/subModule2.module#SubModule2Module' },
    ]
}
```

];

Then when you load /user SubModule1 would be lazy loaded and on /user/subPath2 SubModule2 would be lazy loaded

Comment: Hi, @daddycool I want the profile route to be on the root path. The first tab should be on www.example.com and the second tab should be on www.example.com/subpath

Comment: @doorman Wouldn't it be easier to place it in root module then?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but the problem is if I place the tab routes in the root module the modules are not loaded into the tab control instead they replace the whole profile module which holds the tabcontrol